# Add multimedia keyboard shortcuts in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, multimedia

How do you add (or change) multimedia key shortcuts in Xubuntu.

Specfically I would like to set the Forward and Back keys to Next and Previous tracks in Exaile using the xkeys plugin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't use XFCE myself but I found [this thread](http://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=6729) that suggests that you can use the keyboard settings to set `XF86AudioNext` to `exaile --next` and `XF86AudioPrev` to `exaile --prev`. If that doesn't work out of the box, you may need to see what keycodes these media keys use with `xev` and put them in your .Xmodmap as described in the [FAQ](http://wiki.xfce.org/faq#keyboard).

Comment: xev doesn't appear to see them or if it does I can't see them. Also - if I put them in xmodmap then what would happen with other apps that see the forward and back keys perfectly ok.

Comment: @Elfy That other applications see them all right indicates to me that the so called keysym names are fine and you shouldn't need to map keycodes to them with xmodmap. I take it configuring the XFCE keyboard settings as described doesn't work either? You can also try evtest (it's in a package of the same name), see also this thread http://ask.fedoraproject.org/question/498/why-doesnt-my-key-show-up-in-xev

Comment: The same worked in Banshee for me, thanks! (`banshee --next, --previous, --toggle-playback`)